# A question about sherman–morrison formula

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

For an $n \times n$ non-singular symmetric matrix A and n-dimensional column vectors u and v satisfying $u'A^{-1}v \neq 1$, prove

$$u' (A - uv')^{-1} v = \frac{u'A^{-1}v}{1-   u'A^{-1}v}$$

I already find that

$$(A - uv')^{-1} = A^{-1}+  \frac{A^{-1} uv' A^{-1}}{1-   u'A^{-1}v}$$

But I don't know how to prove the

$$u' (A - uv')^{-1} v = \frac{u'A^{-1}v}{1-   u'A^{-1}v}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from what you have shown,

$$
(A - uv')^{-1} = A^{-1} + \frac{A^{-1} uv' A^{-1}}{1 - u' A^{-1} v} ,
$$
just multiply both sides by $u'$ and $v$ on the left and right respectively to get what you want on the left hand-side. Simplify the right-hand side to obtain
$$
\begin{align}
u' A^{-1} v + \frac{u' A^{-1} uv' A^{-1} v}{1 - u' A^{-1} v}
&= \frac{u' A^{-1} v - (u' A^{-1} v) (u' A^{-1} v) + (u' A^{-1} u) (v' A^{-1} v)}{1 - u' A^{-1} v} \\
&= \frac{u' A^{-1} v}{1 - u' A^{-1} v} .
\end{align}
$$
The key is that $u' A^{-1} v$ is a scalar, so it is equal to its transpose $v' A^{-1} u$ and hence can be used to cancel out the terms in the numerator.

Comment: This is the exactly what I attempt before. But I cannot cancel out the terms.  I agree with you it is equal to its transpose. But there is no transpose here.

Comment: The two bracketed terms I have written are equal: $(u' A^{-1} v) (u' A^{-1} v) = (u' A^{-1} u) (v' A^{-1} v)$. I mean that you transpose the scalar expression: it is a number so you are simply rearranging the order of matrix operations, and you use the fact that $A^{-1}$ is symmetric too.

Comment: Yes, I am stuck here. Can you explain why they are equal?

Comment: $u' A^{-1} v = (u' A^{-1} v)' = v' A^{-1} u$.

Comment: But the right hand side, there is no $v' A^{-1} u$. Instead, it is $v' A^{-1} v$ and $u' A^{-1} u$

Comment: Yes you are quite right about that -- I am being confused by all the $u$'s and $v$'s myself. I have checked your result and it doesn't actually seem to be true (you can test it on a random matrix). What is true (and fixes this proof) is if you consider $v' (A - uv')^{-1} u$ on the left-hand side instead (and the right-hand side is the same) -- then the equality would be true and the proof runs through.